# Pygame collision registers hit all the time

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision, mask

I'm trying to change collision for my game and I saw pygame has mask collision so I tried to use it, but collision is registered all the time and I dont know how to fix it

Here's my code

Class Enemy for fishes spawning in from both sides of the screen and Respawning after hit

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.x_change = 0

    def enemySpawn(self, i, x, x_change, y, img, screen):
        if i < 6:
            if x[i] <= -64 or x[i] >= 900:
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    x[i] = random.randint(-64, 0)
                    x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
                else:
                    x[i] = random.randint(834, 900)
                    x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
                y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)

        elif 5 < i < 10:
            if x[i] <= -128 or x[i] >= 964:
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    x[i] = random.randint(-128, -64)
                    x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
                else:
                    x[i] = random.randint(900, 964)
                    x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
                y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)

        elif i > 9:
            if x[i] <= -256 or x[i] >= 1028:
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    x[i] = random.randint(-256, -128)
                    x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
                else:
                    x[i] = random.randint(964, 1028)
                    x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
                y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)
        screen.blit(img[i], (x[i], y[i]))
        self.rect = img[i].get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(img[i])

    def enemyRespawn(self, i, x, x_change, y, img, screen):
        if i < 6:
            if i % 2 == 1:
                x[i] = random.randint(-64, 0)
                x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
            else:
                x[i] = random.randint(834, 900)
                x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
            y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)

        elif 5 < i < 10:
            if i % 2 == 1:
                x[i] = random.randint(-128, -64)
                x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
            else:
                x[i] = random.randint(900, 964)
                x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
            y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)

        elif i > 9:
            if i % 2 == 1:
                x[i] = random.randint(-256, -128)
                x_change[i] = abs(x_change[i])
            else:
                x[i] = random.randint(964, 1028)
                x_change[i] = -x_change[i]
            y[i] = random.randint(0, 500)
        screen.blit(img[i], (x[i], y[i]))
        self.rect = img[i].get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(img[i])
```

Class Player, that's a shark that moves by key input and get's bigger by eating

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 420
        self.y = 270
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.lastKey = 'l'
        self.score = 0
        self.height = 128
        self.width = 128
        self.keyInput = True

    def drawImg(self, x, y, img, screen):
        screen.blit(img, (x, y))

    def setDimenzije(self, img):
        self.height = img.get_height()
        self.width = img.get_width()

    def playerMovement(self, img, screen):
        # Provera u koju stranu ide
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keyInput:
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.x_change = -1.5
                self.direction = -1
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.x_change = +1.5
                self.direction = 1
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.x_change = 0
            if not (pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
                self.x_change = 0
            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.y_change = -1.5
            if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y_change = +1.5
            if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y_change = 0
            if not (pressed[pygame.K_UP] or pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]):
                self.y_change = 0

        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change

        if self.direction == 1 or self.lastKey == 'r':
            img_flip = pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
            if 5 < self.score < 50:
                self.setDimenzije(img_flip)
                self.drawImg(self.x, self.y, img_flip, screen)
            else:
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img_flip, (64, 64))
                self.setDimenzije(img)
                self.drawImg(self.x, self.y, img, screen)
        elif self.lastKey == 'l':
            if 5 < self.score < 50:
                self.setDimenzije(img)
                self.drawImg(self.x, self.y, img, screen)
            else:
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (64, 64))
                self.setDimenzije(img)
                self.drawImg(self.x, self.y, img, screen)

        if self.x <= -60:
            self.x = 900
        elif self.x >= 900:
            self.x = -60
        if self.y >= 534:
            self.y = 534
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.y = 0
        self.rect = img.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(img)
```

Main Class that has my Collision

```
enemyImg = []
        
 player = Player()
 enemy = Enemy()
 enemySprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

 def main():
    # Inicijalizacija
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    num_of_enemies = 12

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 48)

    # kreiram ekran
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))

    # Pozadina
    pozadina = pygame.image.load("pozadina.png")

    # Naslov i ikona
    pygame.display.set_caption("Gladna ajkula")
    icon = pygame.image.load("sharkIcon.png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    enemyImg0 = pygame.image.load("fish1smol-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg1 = pygame.image.load("fish1smol-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg2 = pygame.image.load("fish2smol-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg3 = pygame.image.load("fish2smol-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg4 = pygame.image.load("fish3smol-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg5 = pygame.image.load("fish3smol-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg6 = pygame.image.load("fish1med-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg7 = pygame.image.load("fish1med-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg8 = pygame.image.load("fish3med-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg9 = pygame.image.load("fish3med-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg10 = pygame.image.load("orca-left.png").convert_alpha()
    enemyImg11 = pygame.image.load("orca-right.png").convert_alpha()

    enemyImg = [enemyImg0, enemyImg1, enemyImg2, enemyImg3, enemyImg4, enemyImg5, enemyImg6, enemyImg7, enemyImg8,
            enemyImg9, enemyImg10, enemyImg11]

    # Igrac
    playerImgLevo1 = pygame.image.load("SharkScaleLeft.png").convert_alpha()
    playerImgDesno1 = pygame.image.load("SharkScaleRight.png").convert_alpha()

    player.keyInput = True

    enemyList = []
    enemyX = []
    enemyY = []
    enemyX_change = []

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            enemyX.append(random.randint(-64, 0))
            enemyX_change.append(1)
        else:
            enemyX.append(random.randint(850, 900))
            enemyX_change.append(-1)
        enemyY.append(random.randint(0, 500))
        enemyList.append(enemy)

    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(120)
        # Pozadina
        screen.blit(pozadina, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        player.playerMovement(playerImgLevo1, screen)

        # Enemy
        for i in range(12):
            enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
            enemy.enemySpawn(i, enemyX, enemyX_change, enemyY, enemyImg, screen)
            enemySprite.add(enemy)

           mob_hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemySprite, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
            #mob_hits = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player, enemyList[i])
            if mob_hits:
                 if player.width > enemyImg[i].get_width():
                 enemy.enemyRespawn(i, enemyX, enemyX_change, enemyY, enemyImg, screen)
                 player.score += 1
                 print('hit')
```

I know it's kinda messy at this point, but i tried to get hit with just collide mask, and spritecollide but i don't know where did I go wrong.
Enemies just keep respawning countless times and pump my score to 1000 in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the collision detection functions like `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` the `rect` attribute  of the `pygame.sprtie.Sprite` objects is used. Therefore you need to make sure that the position of the sprite is set in the `rect` attribute of the `Enemy`

<s>`self.rect = img[i].get_rect()`</s>

```py
self.rect = img[i].get_rect(topleft = (x[i], y[i]))
```

and the `Player`

<s>`self.rect = img.get_rect()`</s>

```py
self.rect = img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
```

Note, [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top left of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm. I was smashing my head for hours on this thank you